# How can I distinguish an element is in left or right sub-tree

Tags: algorithm, math

Suppose that we have a tree structure like that:

[image: example tree]

This consists of 15 nodes, it can be greater or less than this. But order is exact, tree give nodes order numbers from left to right and top to bottom.

The question is: How can I distinguish if a node is in left sub-tree(2-4-5-8-9-10-..) or right sub-tree(3-6-7-12-...).

What I expect is, finding a math formula or coding algorithm that shows me sub-tree which node located. Only input/value is order number of elements.

Comment: Can you use any information about the node (for example its depth?)

Comment: each node stores just one data, so i need to use their order to distinguish.

Comment: In the left sub-tree, every nodes value has a 2nd most significant bit of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your number is N.

You can find the row N is on via R = floor(log<sub>2</sub>(N)) (starting from 0).

The first and last numbers on this row are 2<sup>R</sup> and 2<sup>R+1</sup>-1, respectively. So you just need to figure out which of these endpoints N is closer to.

Specifically, N is in the left subtree iff:

N - 2<sup>R</sup> < 2<sup>R+1</sup> - 1 - N

Rearranging and substituting:

N < (3*2<sup>floor(log<sub>2</sub>(N))</sup> - 1) / 2

---

Sanity check using Python 3 (`True` means left subtree; `False` means right):

```
>>> from math import floor, log2
>>> for N in range(1,16):
...     print(N, N < (3*2**floor(log2(N)) - 1)/2)
...
1 False
2 True
3 False
4 True
5 True
6 False
7 False
8 True
9 True
10 True
11 True
12 False
13 False
14 False
15 False
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @arshajii works, although I would argue that `1` should not be considered to be in the left sub-tree. That answer also is a good "math formula", using standard mathematical functions. However, that answer uses floating-point arithmetic for a problem that involves only integers. Here is another way to solve your problem.

If you look at the binary expansions of the numbers in your tree, you will see that the numbers in the left sub-tree have a `0` bit in the second-most significant bit, while the numbers in the right sub-tree have a `1` bit in the second-most significant bit. Checking for that bit is easy and quick to do, though just how to do that varies between programming languages.

Here are two ways to do that in Python 3:

```
not (n & (1 << n.bit_length() - 2))
```

or

```
bin(n)[3]=='0'
```

To check for the right sub-tree, remove the `not` from the first method or change the `0` to `1` in the second method.

On my system, @arshajii's answer takes 1.34 milliseconds to work (checking with `%timeit`). My first method takes 260 microseconds while my second takes 257 microseconds. So either of my methods is over five times faster than @arshajii's code. A similar check of my code is

```
for n in range(2,16):
    print(bin(n)[3]== '0')
```

and yields

```
True
False
True
True
False
False
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
```